# Setting class data inside axios.get().then() has no effect on the data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I have the following ES6 code:

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemsWithData: []
    };
    this.details =  [1, 2, 3] ;
  }

  loadDetails = items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
      axios
        .get(item.url)
        .then(response => {
          this.details = response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.warn(`Error while getting ${item.name} details`);
        });
    });
    console.log(this.details);//It prints [1,2,3]
  };

}
```

As you can see, I'm setting `this.details` inside `then`.I've logged the `this.details`inside `then` just to make sure it sees the class context. It indeed does. But somehow, setting the details seems to have no effect at the function end. It prints the old value. The response returned from the request has absolutely different data each time. So it's never [1,2,3]. What should I do to get the details data changed appropriately? Is it something to do with async-await?

P.S. In fact, the content of the arrow function passed to `then` is this:

```
this.details[item.name]=response.data;
```

So, I'm not stupidly setting details to a new value at each turn.

Comment: arrow functions don't have `this` so you need to use the oldskool `function(){}` instead

Comment: @bdbdbd No this is fine, he wants to inherit the scope of this from the parent class, which he is doing fine in this example.

Comment: I know they don't have it. But I also know that they refer to the outtermost non arrow function context. Don't they?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your arrow functions referring to the wrong context. The problem is that they are running at the wrong time - asynchronously, after you had logged the old value.

Comment: In fact I've tried to wait for the axios get response by doing like this: `const response = await axios.get(url);
      this.details = response.data;` But still it didn't help. I of cource made the out arrow function (that of the forEach function) async.

Comment: I tried to go Promise.all way but that did not meet my needs, as inside each promise resolve iteration I need to access the current array item property. I eventually switched to normal for loop from for each by